# Tag wiki / mouse over — include tag name?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt

I've been looking at the mouse-over text for tag recently. Seems like some include the text of the tag while others don't. Is there a preferred wording?

EG: [php](/questions/tagged/php)

> "PHP is an open-source server-side scripting language..."

EG: [caching](/questions/tagged/caching)

> "The process of transparently storing data to improve response time."

Comment: Adding the name of the tag to the tag description doesn't really add any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using a sentence, rather than a phrase, but this doesn't necessary mean to include the tag name. For example, the excerpt could be similar to the following one:

> This tag is deprecated, and it will be removed. Don't use it.